# How can I retrieve element Id for Strolngly typed ASP.NET MVC HTML helper?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Client Id for Property (ASP.Net MVC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065307/client-id-for-property-asp-net-mvc)

In my View I'm using jquery ui datapicker.
So I need initiate it with code like this

```
$(function() {
        $('#elementID').datepicker({
        });
});
```

In my View

```
     <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.StartDate) %>
```

In old ASP.NET I may use

```
    tb_startDate.ClientID
```

What is about retrieving element Id of Strongly Typed ASP.NET MVC HTML Helper?
Is is possible?

Comment: Look this
http://www.dominicpettifer.co.uk/Blog/37/strongly-typed--label--elements-in-asp-net-mvc-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way of receiving the id of the textbox once it has been rendered (as it just outputs plain text).

You can, however use another approach where you set the class and use a standard ".class-jquery selector".

Like so:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.StartDate, new { @class = "startDate" }) %>
```

and:

```
$('input.startDate').datepicker();
```

Comment: 10x for your advise, but I'm thinking(and googling) about another solution. Yours is not a good idea in terms of performance.

Comment: I'm not sure the proposed solution has any issues with regards to performance at all. I'd be interested to see a link that suggested otherwise :)

Comment: http://www.dominicpettifer.co.uk/Blog/37/strongly-typed--label--elements-in-asp-net-mvc-2

Comment: Sure, selecting by ids is faster. But for just 1 to 100 selectors on one page, I wouldn't bother implementing a custom helper just to get the Id as it is not that much faster (we're talking milliseconds).

Answer (score 1):

You can create

```
public static class HtmlExtensions 
{ 
    public static MvcHtmlString FieldIdFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression) 
    { 
        string htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression); 
        string inputFieldId = html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(htmlFieldName); 
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(inputFieldId); 
    } 
}
```

and used used it

```
$('@Html.FieldIdFor(m=>m.StartDate').datepicker();
```

For more details: http://www.dominicpettifer.co.uk/Blog/37/strongly-typed--label--elements-in-asp-net-mvc-2