# Client Id for Property (ASP.Net MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, clientid

I'm trying to do a label for a TextBox in my View and I'd like to know, how can I take a Id that will be render in client to generate scripts... for example:

```
<label for="<%=x.Name.ClientId%>"> Name: </label>
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Name) %>
```

What do I need to put in "ClientId" to make sure that the correct Id will be rendered to the corresponding control?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Put this code somewhere:

```
using System; 
using System.Linq.Expressions; 
using System.Web.Mvc; 

namespace MvcLibrary.Extensions 
{ 
    public static class HtmlExtensions 
    { 
        public static MvcHtmlString FieldIdFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
            Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression) 
        { 
            string htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression); 
            string inputFieldId = html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(htmlFieldName); 
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(inputFieldId); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Then in your ASPX view:

```
<label for="<%= Html.FieldIdFor(m => m.EmailAddress) %>">E-mail address:</label> 
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress) %>
```

You can also use this in JavaScript calls as you won't know the control's ID in advance and may need it for some JavaScript code to work against it:

```
<script> $.CoolJQueryFunction('<%= Html.FieldIdFor(m => m.EmailAddress) %>'); </script>
```

The LabelFor HTML helper method, that someone mentioned here, won't let you specify the actual text label you want to use, you have to decorate your ViewModels with attributes to set the label text, with IMHO is ugly. I'd rather that stuff appear in the actual ASPX view part itself, not on some domain/view model. Some people will disagree with me though.

Not sure of the rules for posting links to one's blog posts, but I posted a blog on this exact topic: http://www.dominicpettifer.co.uk/Blog/37/strongly-typed--label--elements-in-asp-net-mvc-2

Comment: I know, but some people can't understand correctly (my english isn't very well)! That's all I need... Thanks a lot Man! Decorate domain model classes with attributies isn't a good pratice for me, I agree with you!

Comment: See my answer below this is no longer required

Answer (score 27):

MVC 4 has this built in now.. see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833709%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

Its fun what can be found at free source code of MVC. Here is the answer:

**@Html.IdFor** or
**@Html.NameFor**

So what is the difference? Here is the catch:

The NameFor would not replace any "." to "_".

If you want any example, [I have found this cool small article](http://www.nickriggs.com/posts/getting-the-id-and-name-attribute-generated-by-typed-html-helpers/)

Answer (score 0):

As has been said, you don't need to worry about ClientID, UniqueID etc in ASP.NET MVC as those are webforms abstractions. You can simply just write out the ID that you want. There is also an extension method for this:

```
<%= Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name) %>
```

Comment: LabelFor will give you a strongly typed <label> but doesn't let you specify the actual label text itself, you have to set it against the ViewModel itself as a Property Attribute, this is a weird omission to me.

Answer (score -2):

Use the following:

```
Model.Name
```

You can simply do a "view source" or examine the rendered textbox with something like Firebug to see what the `Html.xyzFor()` methods are generating.  Normally they would generate a textbox with the "id" and "name" attributes both set to the property name.

Comment: it'll write the content of the property, and I don't need it.. i need the Name of the Property (or Client Id... if there is one... i don't know excatly)

Comment: @FelipeOriani @womp while using `Html.LabelFor(x => x.Id)` it is showing me the "Id" Text which i defined  `DisplayName` of Id instead of Id value which is coming from DB. Any comments?