# Retrieve input id generated by asp.net

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have an input box generated by

```
 <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Card.ExpiryDate) %>
```

which results in the html

```
<input id="Card_Expiry_Date" name="Card.ExpiryDate" type="text" value="">
```

I also have javascript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $().ready(function() {
   $('#Card_Expiry_Date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
</script>
```

How can I retrieve the input id that will be generated so that I don't have to hard-code the id in my function?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065307/client-id-for-property-asp-net-mvc/3069808#3069808

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Ahmad for you comment, that was what I was looking for!

[Client Id for Property (ASP.Net MVC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065307/client-id-for-property-asp-net-mvc/3069808#3069808)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the ID when creating the textbox:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Card.ExpiryDate, new { id="Card_ExpiryDate" })  %>
```

Then this will surely work:

```
 $('#Card_ExpiryDate')...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure for MVC, but in Forms you would inject the textbox id into the html.  Something akin to:

```
$get('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>')
```

Link with explanation [here](http://encosia.com/2007/08/08/robust-aspnet-control-referencing-in-javascript/).