# How to specify ID for an Html.LabelFor<> (MVC Razor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Client Id for Property (ASP.Net MVC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065307/client-id-for-property-asp-net-mvc)

Is there a way to make Razor render an ID attribute for a Label element when using the Html.LabelFor<> helper?

Example:

```
.cshtml page
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Foo)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Foo)
}
```

Rendered page

```
<form ...>
<label for="Foo" id="Label_Foo" />
<input type="text" name="Foo" id="Foo" />
</form>
```

FYI - The sole reason I'm wanting to add an ID to the Label is for CSS design. I'd prefer to reference the Label by an ID rather than wrapping the Label within a block (i.e. div) and then styling the block.

Comment: why do you have to do m => m.Foo why not just m.Foo

Comment: Because you have to insert an expression which can be read rather than insert a value.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no built-in overload of this helper that allows you to achieve this.

Fortunately it would take a couple of lines of code to implement your own:

```
public static class LabelExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, 
        object htmlAttributes
    )
    {
        return LabelHelper(
            html,
            ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData),
            ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression),
            htmlAttributes
        );
    }

    private static MvcHtmlString LabelHelper(
        HtmlHelper html, 
        ModelMetadata metadata,
        string htmlFieldName, 
        object htmlAttributes
    )
    {
        string resolvedLabelText = metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(resolvedLabelText))
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }

        TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("label");
        tag.Attributes.Add("for", TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(htmlFieldName)));
        tag.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
        tag.SetInnerText(resolvedLabelText);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
}
```

and once brought into scope use this helper in your view:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Foo, new { id = "Foo" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Foo)
```

Remark: because now it is up to you to manage HTML ids, make sure that they are unique throughout the entire document.

Remark2: I have shamelessly plagiarized and modified the `LabelHelper` method from the ASP.NET MVC 3 source code.

Comment: This method is supported in the latest versions of MVC without the extension.

Answer (score 1):

And for the normal label `@Html.Label()`, you can do it like this:

```
public static HtmlString Label(this HtmlHelper helper, string target = "", string text = "", string id = "")
{
    return new HtmlString(string.Format("<label id='{0}' for='{1}'>{2}</label>", id, target, text));
}
```