# How can I set LabelFor to be hidden

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am able to write in my MVC 3 view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Something, new { style = "display: none;" })
```

But how can I do the same with a LabelFor?

To explain why: I am hiding the label initially but using JQuery to show this label at a later point. I guess I can use JQuery to initially hide it as well, but I would rather do it this way is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this post [How to specify ID for an Html.LabelFor<> (MVC Razor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255138/how-to-specify-id-for-an-html-labelfor-mvc-razor)

Comment: Thanks. I think that your suggestion about just wrapping it in a hidden element (before your edit) should be enough for now, but the knowledge for how to specify ID for labelfor is great for later use.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd suggest you wrap the TextBox and Label in a containing div, set that element to display:none and have JQuery show/hide the containing div rather than the individual elements.