# Make KendoUI Textboxes of same width

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have the following cshtml Login form:

```
<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserEmailAddress)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserEmailAddress, new {@class = "k-textbox", style="width:200px"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserEmailAddress)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserPassword)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserPassword, new { @class = "k-textbox", style="width:200px" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserPassword)
        </div>
```

The email address is of typr class `k-textbox` but the password is `text-box single-line password`. Therefore both of the have different widths. Even after I tried to specify width and class explicitly. i'm using KendoUI for MVC. 
The Output is : 
[image]

This is the page source:

```
 <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="UserEmailAddress">User Name (Email Id)</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input class="k-textbox" data-val="true" data-val-regex="E-mail is not valid" data-val-regex-pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$" data-val-required="The User Name (Email Id) field is required." id="UserEmailAddress" name="UserEmailAddress" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="UserEmailAddress" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="UserPassword">UserPassword</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input class="text-box single-line password" data-val="true" data-val-required="Password required" id="UserPassword" name="UserPassword" type="password" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="UserPassword" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
```

How can these both be made of same class, style and width.

Comment: Apart from the `k-textbox` class that is defined by Kendo, whats is relevance of the Kendo tag? Have you tried removing the `k-textbox` class to see if that's the source of your problem? Could you also please provide the part of the rendered HTML code corresponding to your login section?

Comment: If I make both the textboxes `k-textbox` in firebug both have same width.

Comment: You need to inspect the text boxes better. See the computed values for your text boxes. See also what those "single-line" and "password" classes produce and if they affect the width or not. Observe that your password text box does not have `k-textbox` but `text-box`. You use standard HTML helpers for rendering and not Kendo helpers, so passing the `new {@class = "k-textbox", style="width:200px"}` does not produce anything.

Comment: If you're still out there, can we see your Model?  Since you're using `EditorFor`, I'm guessing that there might be some Attributes on the properties in your Model that are impacting the `EditorFor` output.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the best solution for your case would be to write your own custom HTML helper, that will allow you to pass additional information to your text box. See [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255138/how-to-specify-id-for-an-html-labelfor-mvc-razor) for instructions.

If you don't want to mess with custom HTML helpers, just write plain HTML code instead:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <input style="width:200px;" class="k-textbox single-line password" data-val="true" data-val-required="Password required" id="UserPassword" name="UserPassword" type="password" value="" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="UserPassword" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep I noticed kendo uses the class .text-box and single-line instead of k-textbox on certain input fields. I think it happens when the fields are of a certain type like numbers. You can just restyle the .text-box class to match the .k-texbox.

Update:
Actually I was able to add the class k-textbox to the input fields using MVC 5 syntax. Was able to remove classes for .text-box.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "k-textbox" } })
```

Update:
Just found another way. In the Model I think if you annotate password property with [DataType(DataType.Password)], then in the ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates folder there should be a file named Password.cshtml. This is the template that is being used to display when using Html.EditorFor and DataType is Password. The template should add the k-textbox class to make both fields consistent.

```
@model object 

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model, new { @class = "k-textbox", type = "password", autocomplete = "off", placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark })
```

Answer (score 1):

Kendo UI overwrites the styles when you use EditorFor. Use TextBoxFor instead.