# How can I display the client ID of a model property into a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my view I want to be able to render out the ID of a model property independent of an associated control markup.

So for example, if my model was:

```
public class Author {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

In my view I would preferably like to be able to use an extension of `HtmlHelper` to render out the `Title` property's ID using a lambda. Something like:

`@Html.GetClientIdFor(x => x.Title)`

And this would output "Title".

In the case of nested objects, I would like:

`@Html.GetClientIdFor(x => x.Address.PostCode)`

to output "Address_PostCode".

I'm sure I can access the data from the `ViewData.TemplateInfo` object but from there I'm a little stuck.

Any ideas? I am using MVC4 but I would like a solution that worked for MVC3 too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, there is an `HtmlHelper` that does exactly what you want: [`IdFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833709%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

```
@Html.IdFor(x => x.Address.PostCode) // Will return Address_PostCode
```

Although, that's for MVC4 and up. For MVC3, you will need to roll your own. See [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3069808/2518184).